# Artifactory REST Deploy screwing up upload

Tags: c#, http, rest, restsharp, artifactory

I am trying to deploy artifacts to artifactory using their REST API, however all my files end up having

> -------------------------------28947758029299 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="test.txt"; filename="new2.txt" Content-Type:
>   application/octet-stream

appended to the file. Here is my code (keep in mind this is only me testing the concept...the code will be cleaned after I get a success)

```
  var uriString = "artifactoryuri";
  var uri = new Uri(uriString);
  var credentialCache = new CredentialCache{{uri, "Basic",new NetworkCredential("UN", "PW")}};
  var restClient = new RestClient(uriString);
  var restRequest = new RestRequest(Method.PUT){Credentials = credentialCache};
  restRequest.AddFile("test.txt", @"pathto\new2.txt");
  var restResponse = restClient.Execute(restRequest);
```

How can I fix this? Is it because it is a text file and artifactory tends to store executables and such? If so, I can live with that. This will be used to upload chm files currently.

Comment: You're trying to POST "form" data; the entire request body should be the contents of your file

Comment: @noamt But per the docs, I want to PUT the data. And all I am adding is the file?

Comment: This is caused by the `AddFile` method - `RestSharp` will create a multipart/form request by default. I could not find a good solution for preventing this behavior, although many people ask about it. You can take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158977/can-restsharp-send-binary-data-without-using-a-multipart-content-type and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/restsharp/A3zv2DEZEDw

Comment: Hrmm, not sure if this is beneficial to others or not. If either of you make your comment as an answer, then I will accept. Otherwise, I will delete

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the `AddFile` method - RestSharp will create a `multipart/form` request by default. I could not find a good solution for preventing this behavior, although many people ask about it. You can take a look at [Can RestSharp send binary data without using a multipart content type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158977/can-restsharp-send-binary-data-without-using-a-multipart-content-type) and [PUT method and send raw bytes](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/restsharp/A3zv2DEZEDw)