# Face API Base64 image post returns badrequest

Tags: c#, rest, azure-cognitive-services

Face API works with URL of the image but when I try to send image as 
Base64 encoded it returns an error.
In this sample code I used Restsharp to send the data

My code is like below.

```
 public string GenerateRest(String Base64Image)
    {
        var serviceURL = Constants.BaseServiceURI;
        var client = new RestClient(serviceURL);

        var request = new RestRequest(Constants.BaseResoruce, Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", Constants.MS_API_KEY);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");

        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

        var baseString = Base64Image.Replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", String.Empty);

        byte[] newBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(baseString);

        request.AddBody(newBytes);
        // execute the request
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        var content = response.Content; // raw content as string

        return content;
    }
```

After fixing Restsharp request according to answer code is like

```
 public FaceAPIOutput GenerateRest(String Base64Image)
    {
        var serviceURL = Constants.BaseServiceURI;
        var client = new RestClient(serviceURL);
        var baseString = Base64Image.Replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", String.Empty);
        byte[] newBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(baseString);

        var request = new RestRequest(Constants.BaseResoruce, Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", Constants.MS_API_KEY);
        request.AddParameter("application/octet-stream", newBytes, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        var content = response.Content; // raw content as string

        return ConvertToFaceAPIOutObject(content);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Restsharp looks a bit idiosyncratic when taking a binary payload.  Instead of `request.AddBody`, which adds a multipart form section, you need to do the following:

```
request.AddParameter("application/octet-stream", newBytes, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

c.f. [Can RestSharp send binary data without using a multipart content type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158977/can-restsharp-send-binary-data-without-using-a-multipart-content-type)