# Uploading files to sharepoint with RestSharp and their rest API is adding header and trailer lines to every file

Tags: rest, file-upload, sharepoint-online, restsharp

I'm uploading to sharepoint using a c# client, and every file I Upload gets extra data included. A one line CSV file gets turned into a 7 line file that isn't usable. This is what my one line file upload turned into:

```
-----------AEE7A299-297A-41E0-B1CC-A72050FCDD28 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ControlFile_RCTI_statement_20220218_145832.csv"; filename="ControlFile_RCTI_statement_20220218_145832.csv"    
Content-Type: application/octet-stream  

File;Class;Account Number;Effective Date;Product;Account Type;Document Name 

-----------AEE7A299-297A-41E0-B1CC-A72050FCDD28--
```

My upload code is using restSharp

```
public async Task UploadFile(string filePath, string list, string folderPath)
{
    await CheckTokenAsync();
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
    var endpoint = $"{spCredentials.sharepointSubSiteFullUrl}/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('{list}/{folderPath}')/Files/Add(url='{fileName}', overwrite=false)";
    var client = new RestClient(endpoint);
    client.Timeout = 30000;
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");
    request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
    request.AddFile(fileName, filePath);
    var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        var fileData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SPSingleResultContainer>(response.Content);
        var link = fileData.d.__metadata.uri;
        await SendRequest<string>($"{link}/CheckIn()", Method.POST);
    }
    else
        throw new Exception($"Upload Failed with message: " + response.ErrorMessage);
}
```

I've also added this question to the sharepoint SE at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/300550/uploading-files-to-sharepoint-with-restsharp-and-their-rest-api-is-adding-header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out RestSharp was doing a multipart upload, and sharepoint doesn't like that sort of thing. Other people have had [This Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45379538/restsharp-addfile-adding-multipart-form-headers-to-file) with RestSharp

```
public async Task UploadFile(string filePath, string list, string folderPath)
{
    var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
    await UploadFileData(Path.GetFileName(filePath), list, folderPath, bytes);
    return;
}
public async Task UploadFileData(string fileName, string list, string folderPath, byte[] fileData)
{
    await CheckTokenAsync();
    var endpoint = $"{spCredentials.sharepointSubSiteFullUrl}/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('{list}/{folderPath}')/Files/Add(url='{fileName}', overwrite=false)";
    var client = new RestClient(endpoint);
    client.Timeout = 30000;
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");
    request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
    string contentType = "";
    var fileType = Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToLower();
    switch (fileType)//there are better ways to get the MIME type, I was just getting desperate and trying everything
    {
        case ".csv":
            contentType = "text/csv";
            break;
        case ".xlsx":
            contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            break;
        case ".pdf":
            contentType = "application/pdf";
            break;
        case ".html":
            contentType = "text/html";
            break;
        default:
            throw new NotImplementedException($"File type {fileType} not supported");
    }
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", contentType);
    request.AddParameter(contentType, fileData, ParameterType.RequestBody);

    var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);

    var test = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        var fileMetaData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SPSingleResultContainer>(response.Content);
        var link = fileMetaData.d.__metadata.uri;
        await SendRequest<string>($"{link}/CheckIn()", Method.POST);
    }
    else
        throw new Exception($"Upload {fileName} Failed with status {response.StatusCode} and message: " + response.ErrorMessage);
}
```

For anyone coming here that doesn't care about sharepoint, replacing .addfile with

```
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", contentType);
request.AddParameter(contentType, fileData, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

where contentType is the MIME format of your file extension (or an empty string seems to work as well) solved the issue for me.