# How to save data to other than text file in C#

Tags: c#, file, io

Im wondering how to save data in other types of file than text file, for example save it to raw file without any encoding, I mean just save a byte value, so you will get something like this when trying to edit it in text editor:https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyhWS.png

Comment: Without an encoding, there is no "byte value" assigned to a character.

Comment: Just use a `Stream` - that deals with binary data rather than text...

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to convert your string to a byte array. See the following SO answer: [String to raw byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2614051/928483). You can then write the byte array to a file.

In the `System.Text.Encoding` namespace are some encodings with methods you can use to convert a string to a byte array easily. Depending on the contents of your string you could use eg:

```
var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
var bytes = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(input);
```

Writing to a file can be easily archieved by:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(string path, byte[] bytes)
```